# Graph representations in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, graph-theory, swi-prolog, adjacency-list

Consider the following graph

[image]

and that it is described by the below Prolog term :

`graph([connected(a,[b,c]), connected(b,[a,c]), connected(c,[a,b,d]), connected(d,[c]) ]).`

I would like to define a predicate which transforms the above connections into a list of the corresponding pairs. In other words, a predicate which yields
`[[a,b],[a,c],[b,c],[c,d]]` for the above term-graph.

Could you please advise how to do it ?

My attempt so far is the following :

map 2-neighbor vertex to pairs :

```
map2ne(adjacent(H,[K|T]),Pair) :-
    append([H],[K],L),
    append([H],T,M),
    append([L],[M],Pair).
```

*This runs ok.*

map 3-neighbor vertex to pairs :

```
map3n(adjacent(H,[K,L|T]),Pair) :-
    append([H],[K],A1),
    append([H],[L],A2),
    append([A1],[A2],Z),
    append([H],T,M),
    append(Z,[M],Pair).
```

*This also runs ok.*

But when I try to extend it to n-neighbor vertex, then it fails :

```
mapmany(adjacent(H, [K|_]),Pair) :-
    append([H],[K],L),
    append(L,[],Pair),
    mapmany(adjacent(H,[K|_]),M),
    append(M,Pair,Pair).
```

And also the below fails, which was intented to map many n-neighbor vertices to pairs :

```
mapping(Map,Pairs) :-
    select(X,Map,Y),
    mapmany(X,PairX),
    append([PairX],Pairs),
    mapping(Y,Pairs).
```

Comment: In the list describing the graph, the element `connected([d,[c]])` should be `connected(d,[c])`. Show us what you've tried before so we can help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [library(ugraphs)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs): Graph manipulation library

Comment: @slago.. hi, sure.. see my edited post above. Guy Coder I will also go through the built-in fcts of the library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many flaws in your code:

- The adjacency list defined by `graph/1` is composed of terms of the form `connected(Vertex, Neighbors)`; however, your code deals with an adjacency list of terms of the form `adjacent(Vertex, Neighbors)`.
- Predicate `append/3` should not be used to create *all* lists; for example, instead of `append([H], [K], L)`, you should use `L = [H, K]`.
- In Prolog, it is more idiomatic to represent a pair of items `V` and `W` as `V-W`, instead of `[V,W]`.
- By the answer you expect for the example given (i.e., `[a-b,a-c,b-c,c-d]`), a single term `V-W` (i.e., {V,W}) represents both the edges (V,W) and (W,V). So, to avoid redundancy, you must exclusively choose `V-W` or `W-V` to put in your answer (without loss of generality, you can choose the term where `V` precedes `W`).

To to create an edge, you can do the following:

```
edge(V, W, Edge) :-
    (   V @< W
    ->  Edge = V-W
    ;   Edge = W-V ).
```

Examples:

```
?- edge(a, b, Edge).
Edge = a-b.

?- edge(b, a, Edge).
Edge = a-b.
```

To create all edges connecting a vertex `V` to its neighbors `Ns`, without duplicates, just ask:

```
?- V=a, Ns=[b,c,d], setof(E, W^Ns^(member(W,Ns), edge(V,W,E)), Edges).
V = a,
Ns = [b, c, d],
Edges = [a-b, a-c, a-d].
```

Notice that the construct `Var^Goal` tells [setof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) not to bind variable `Var` in `Goal` (in other words, indicates that `Var` is *existentially quantified*).

Generalizing this idea, we have:

```
graph_edges(Graph, Edges) :-
    setof( Edge,
           V^Ns^W^( member(connected(V, Ns), Graph),
                    member(W, Ns),
                    edge(V, W, Edge)),
           Edges ).

graph([connected(a, [b, c]),
       connected(b, [a, c]),
       connected(c, [a, b, d]),
       connected(d, [c])]).
```

Example:

```
?- graph(G), graph_edges(G, E).
G = [connected(a, [b, c]), connected(b, [a, c]), connected(c, [a, b, d]), connected(d, [c])],
E = [a-b, a-c, b-c, c-d].
```

**LIBRARY UGRAPHS**

In SWI-Prolog, a trivial solution would be to use the predicate [edges/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=edges/2) from  `library(ugraphs)`. Be careful though, because the representation of undirected graphs on which the predicate `edge/2` is based is different from the one you are considering (an undirected graph in the `library(ugraphs)` is represented by a list of vertex pairs where the order of the vertices in these pairs matters). For example:

```
?- edges([a-[b,c], b-[a,c], c-[a,b,d], d-[c]], E).
E = [a-b, a-c, b-a, b-c, c-a, c-b, c-d, d-c].
```

Comment: It's much easier and cleaner to define an auxiliary predicate for use with `setof/3`, rather than (a) peppering the code with special syntax, and (b) having to give an incomplete faux explanation of the special syntax to beginners.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie It would be more instructive you to post your simpler and clearer solution (so everyone can learn from it). As for "incomplete faux explanation," I don't understand what you mean. The explanation I gave is based on SWI-Prolog documentation and, if it is wrong, it would be interesting you to contact those responsible for it and help them to correct it.

Comment: It's not *wrong*. But it's unlikely that "oh, that's just existential quantification" will actually lead to any amount of understanding on the part of someone who struggles with basic list processing.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie When I first read The Craft of Prolog [O'Keefe, 1990, p. 364], which says that variables in setof/3 whose values you do not want to know about are "existential" variables that was precisely my reaction: "oh, that's just existential quantification!".

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie As O'Keefe says, "there are three choices for distinguishing free from existentially quantified variables": one of them is to "forbid existentially quantified variables", by defining auxiliary predicates, when you find the setof/3 query you are writting is not clear (that's what you advocate as the best approach); another one is to "label existential variables in some way" (ISO notation ^)  "This, of course, is precisely what is done in logic, so that's what Prolog does" (that's what I've done in my answer, since the condition I've used seems perfectly clear and obvious to me).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a solution based on `setof/3`, I strongly recommend defining an auxiliary predicate. This predicate should define exactly what we want a set of. When we want to define "the set of all edges in the graph", mathematically we might say something like "`Edges` is the set of all `Edge` terms where `Edge` is an edge in `Graph`".

We can write this very directly as follows:

```
graph_edges(Graph, Edges) :-
    setof( Edge,
           graph_edge(Graph, Edge),
           Edges ).
```

It remains to define `graph_edge/2` itself. The core of this can be lifted from slago's solution:

```
graph_edge(Graph, Edge) :-
    member(connected(V, Ns), Graph),
    member(W, Ns),
    edge(V, W, Edge).
```

The advantages of having this as a separate predicate are:

- the `setof` call is easier to read
- the predicate itself has a nice descriptive name
- the predicate can be tested in isolation
- the predicate can be reused
- no `^` signs anywhere, which have no meaning in Prolog except for complicating `setof` calls that don't use an auxiliary predicate
- no worrying about "existential quantification", which has no meaning in Prolog except for complicating `setof` calls that don't use an auxiliary predicate

Comment: Thank you both.. I will go through everything in detail.. This is all very useful to get used to prolog..